# How to return a KML content

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, kml, sharpkml

I'm trying to cook a web api that connects to my DB, fetch some geographical data, then returns a KML content that will be consumed by a webpage (displaying the info on a google maps iframe/div).

I'm using sharpKML (and I don't know if it's the right choice):

```
public class KmlController : ApiController
{
    public HttpResponseMessage Get()
    {
        Point point = new Point();
        point.Coordinate = new Vector(37.42052549, -122.0816695);

        Placemark placemark = new Placemark();
        placemark.Name = "Somewhere";
        placemark.Geometry = point;

        Kml kml = new Kml();
        kml.Feature = placemark;

        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, kml, new XmlMediaTypeFormatter(), "application/vnd.google-earth.kml+xml");
    }
}
```

But when I call http://something.on.my.lan/api/kml I get this exception:

System.InvalidOperationException: 
The 'ObjectContent`1' type failed to serialize the response body for content type 'application/vnd.google-earth.kml+xml; charset=utf-8'.

What am I missing?

**SOLUTION**

Unfortunately, as said in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9228379/496119) answer, even if I manage to create a KML content on the fly, it won't display on a map, because the URL must be publicly accessed by Google (for caching purposes). I have to change approach.

Comment: It is Odd that you are serializing on the method itself. Media Formatters are set on your Register Method on the Global.asax class. I would guess there is a conflict with your formatters

Comment: How do you suggest to do this? I tried als to return a Kml object, without managing serialization myself, but no luck (similar exeption): "The 'ObjectContent`1' type failed to serialize the response body for content type 'application/xml; charset=utf-8'."

Answer (score 1):

Try this first, I wonder if there is an issue with the serialization of any of the objects:

```
private string SerializeObject<T>(this T toSerialize)
{
    XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(toSerialize.GetType());
    StringWriter textWriter = new StringWriter();

    xmlSerializer.Serialize(textWriter, toSerialize);
    return textWriter.ToString();
}


public class KmlController : ApiController
{
    public string Get()
    {
        Point point = new Point();
        point.Coordinate = new Vector(37.42052549, -122.0816695);

        Placemark placemark = new Placemark();
        placemark.Name = "Somewhere";
        placemark.Geometry = point;

        Kml kml = new Kml();
        kml.Feature = placemark;

        return SerializeObject<Kml>(kml);;
    }
}
```

If it fails I recommend you to refer to Serialization documentation so you can find which object is not serializing properly.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serializableattribute.aspx

Comment: Yes, it fails: the exception details are localized, translated it says: Error in reflection of type 'SharpKml.Dom.Kml'.

Comment: It most likely means that one of your objects is not [Serializable]

Comment: I'm starting to think that `<kml>` tag inside `<xml>` has a differenct XML namespace that make the serializer fail...

Comment: The default serializer used by Xml formatter is `DataContractSerializer`, so you can first check serializing your type with that serializer to flush out any serialization issues

Comment: If I use SharpKml specific serializer, I get a good KML string:             var serializer = new Serializer();
serializer.Serialize(kml);
var xml = serializer.Xml;

Comment: Serialization method can be overridden per class but that does not guarantee the class will be compatible with other serializations like in this case XmlMediaFormatters for WebApi

Answer (score 0):

This is working for me...

```
    public static byte[] SerializeKml(this KmlFile kml)
    {
        var serializer = new Serializer(); 
        serializer.Serialize(kml.Root); 
        var str = serializer.Xml;

        var bytes = new byte[str.Length * sizeof(char)];
        Buffer.BlockCopy(str.ToCharArray(), 0, bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
        return bytes;
    }

    public ActionResult GetKml()
    {
        Placemark placemark = new Placemark
        {
            Geometry = new Point { Coordinate = new Vector(-13.163959, -72.545992) },
            Name = "Machu Picchu",
        };

        var kml = KmlFile.Create(placemark, false);
        var fcResult = new FileContentResult(kml.SerializeKml(), "application/vnd.google-earth.kml+xml") { FileDownloadName = "MachuPicchu.kml" };
        return fcResult;
    }
```